# java.exe finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

My previous play service version is 6.5.87 and I upgraded to 7.0.0 then Got this error

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_xx\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

I have upgraded play service Then....Now my gradle is

```
dependencies {
compile project(':com_facebook_android')
compile project(':pullToRefreshLib')
compile project(':smoothProgressbarLib')
compile project(':progressMaterial')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.6.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.4.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-api-client-googleapis-1.4.1-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.6.7.jar')
compile files('libs/jeval.jar')
compile files('libs/jscience.jar')
compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
compile files('libs/guava-r09.jar')
```

Is there any conflict library?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No one answered. I found.... The solution is multidex

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}

}
```

in menifest file

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme">
```

My gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.winapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    multiDexEnabled = true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I am unable to inherit MultiDexApplication :( How to get that?

Comment: Have you added `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` ?

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to include to your gradle only Google Play Services API that you will use. In this link you should select the URIs to compile in your project https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

For example, if you would include only Google analytics you should add only this in your gradle project file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
```